# Activity Actions in Gmail for lightning

Tags: lightning, visualforce-component, gmail

When i open a Contact record in salesforce LTX it give me option of New Task, Log a Call, New Event under Activity Tab as shown below.

[image]

But in Lightning for Gmail when i open contact and goes to Activity Tab i can't see those actions. screenshot of lightning for gmail :-

[image]

So is there any way i can see those buttons there. Currently i am using Global action of New Task and creating a followup task option. But i would love to see these actions in lightning for gmail layout.

Is it even Possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to allow you to do this yet that I can find. It only allows you to edit what shows via app builder and not editing the page layouts.